# WebView causing errors on second activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-webview

I have the following code which works fine when I have it in my main Activity:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.iQuestionWebView);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "test", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Where the WebView layout simply looks like this:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/iQuestionWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

But if I put the layout and the code to my second Activity (a simple LinearLayout), I get the following errors:

> netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib libdnshostprio.so
>
> netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: libdnshostprio.so
>
> netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib spl_proc_plugin.so
>
> netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: spl_proc_plugin.so
>
> netstack: LIB_MGR - Error loading lib pp_proc_plugin.so
>
> netstack: STAT_HUB - Failed to load plugin: pp_proc_plugin.so
>
> netstack:  STAT_HUB - App com.ms.wvtest isn't supported
>
> E/cutils-trace(11142): Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)

As you can see, the code is very basic - a simple button that starts the second Activity:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button startQuiz = (Button)findViewById(R.id.iMainStartQuizButton);
        startQuiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Quiz.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Quiz.java**

```
public class Quiz extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.iQuestionWebView);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "test", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could point me to the cause of the error. Thank you in advance for your help!

**Edit:** As requested quiz.xml and the manifest:

**quiz.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/iQuestionWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
        
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ms.studycards"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/l_app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.ms.studycards.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/l_setup_title" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ms.studycards.Quiz"
            android:label="@string/l_quiz_title"
            android:parentActivityName="com.ms.studycards.MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does `quiz.xml` has the webview?

Comment: Yes, the layout I posted at the top was first in the main Activity and then I moved it to the second one (_quiz.xml_). The app still starts and displays the Strings, btw, but I do get all these errors.

Comment: Post your quiz.xml content AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Done. I also discovered that when I run the app on a local AVD, I only get the error  _E/cutils-trace(2817): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)_ and the other errors only seem to appear on my actual phone (Moto G). This is strange...

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Nope, still unresolved. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved this issue, although I only test my apps on a device (the simulator is too slow).

1. In the manifest file, add the internet permission:

   ```
   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
   ```
2. In your webview (so in Quiz.java), you need to enable javascript:

   ```
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ```

In my case, these 2 things get rid of the problem and display the content (youtube video in my case) in the webview in the device.

Comment: Thanks. I already had the `INTERNET` permission, but enabling javascript fixed the problem for me :D

Comment: Regarding your problem with code blocks:
To make a code block, make sure you have an empty line before the code, then add 4 spaces in front of the code. However, if you are in a list, you need 8 spaces instead of 4, as the first 4 count as if you are simply aligning with the list :)