# what is netstack in android?

Tags: android, networking, stack

what is netstack in android? I got errors similar to this question [on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880037/webview-causing-errors-on-second-activity) but i cannot find any good documentation explaining what is netstack exactly?

Comment: Can you post your errors? Usually it is related to network!

Comment: I am interested in knowing about netstack so that i can understand the errors better.